React State / Passing Information Between Components
I'm pretty new to React (and web development in general), so hopefully I can explain well what I'm looking to do.
To practice using state, I'm building a small app with 3 components. The smallest component (Square.jsx) is a single square(div) that can change to a different color when you click on it. The next component (GroupOfSquares.jsx) loops x number of times and pushes those squares onto an empty array. Right now I'm just looping 5 times, (so it's just displaying a row of 5 color-changing squares). Also within this component is an element that displays the total number of times you've clicked on any of the squares with a "reset" button that will reset the number of times clicked.
Where I'm really struggling is with this reset part. I want the button to also reset the colors, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.
Code here
I've tried lifting the piece of state setting the colors to it's parent component, but it always renders every single square to be the same color, and they all change simultaneously when I click one. I assume because I'm essentially setting the state to apply to the entire group of squares when I move it into the the GroupOfSquares component. I thought maybe the problem was in creating a loop rendering the 5 squares, but after tinkering with that I don't think that has anything to do with it. I also tried adding an additional piece of state in the parent component while leaving my Square component alone, but that wasn't working out well either.
I would appreciate any advice pointing me in the right direction!

Lifting state up is correct, but i think what you missed is that the state needs to become an array of colors, instead of just an individual color. Also, if you want to reset to the exact same random colors, you'll need to remember what those colors were. One option for remembering the random colors is to have a different state which you never change:
const [initialColors] = useState(
  () => Array.from({ length: 5 }).map(() => randomPick(colors))
)
const [currentColors, setCurrentColors] = useState(initialColors);

But since you're not changing it, there are other options as well. You could jot it down in a ref:
const initialColors = useRef(
  Array.from({ length: 5 }).map(() => randomPick(colors))
);
const [currentColors, setCurrentColors] = useState(initialColors.current);

Or you could use useMemo with an empty dependency array:
const initialColors = useMemo(() => {
  return Array.from({ length: 5 }).map(() => randomPick(colors))
}, []);
const [currentColors, setCurrentColors] = useState(initialColors)

Personally, i would probably do the memo version or state version, since they can be set up to make the array just once, and not on every render. But it doesn't make much difference.
Whichever you choose, you'll modify your boxes to be based on the array state that can change:
const boxes = currentColors.map((color, i) => (
  <Square
    key={i}
    color={color}
    onClick={() => {
      setCurrentColors((prev) => {
        const next = [...prev];
        next[i] = randomPick(colors);
        return next;
      });
      setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
    }}
  />
));

// In Square.js:
function Square({ color, onClick }) {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={onClick}
      className="Square"
      style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
    />
  );
}

And to reset, you'll set the count to 0 and the colors to the initialColors
const reset = () => {
  setCount(0);
  setColors(initialColors);
  // Or if you used a ref:
  // setColors(initialColors.current);
}

Sandbox link

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but just wanted to say this was a super clear and very helpful explanation, I really appreciate it!
